# Can pure SVG document specify a favicon.ico?

Tags: svg, favicon

Can a pure SVG document arriving at a browser, support a favicon.ico specification?  My case is machine-generated pure SVG, no `<html>` or `<head>` tags available.

Comment: You could try creating a foreignObject element and sticking the favicon link in that.

Comment: Thanks Robert, this works at least partly.  Works in IE9 but not Firefox.  I suspect this is on the right track for FF, because the default favicon is now absent.  After the first `<svg>` element, I used, `<foreignObject requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <html>
      <head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"></link>
      </head>
</html></foreignObject>'

Comment: Copying and pasting the above works for me on Firefox.

Comment: See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/869) in SVG working group specifications.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, since SVG is XML, you can add the (x)html `link` element anywhere in the SVG:

```xml
<link xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

There's absolutely no need to wrap this in `foreignObject`.
I recommend putting the link element as a child of a `defs` element though, just to let the SVG engines know that it can be skipped for the actual SVG rendering.

Do note that this isn't "pure" SVG; it's an xhtml/svg hybrid — but it should work in all the browsers that support SVG.

Comment: To be clear, some writings said to use `rel="icon"` but I discovered that `rel="shortcut icom"` is required to get IE to act properly.  See the wikipedia article on favicon for more about cross-browser issues.  Thanks again guys!

Comment: I tried your answer but the W3C Validator won't validate it. I tried to define the namespace but to no avail.

<!-- language: lang-xml -->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <title>De mægtige vikinger</title>
      <defs>
        <xhtml:link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
      </defs>
    </svg>

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter So what? Report a bug in the validator to w3c if you want.

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter In this case it appears that the code originally posted works for the OP so you likely have a subtly different question. The way forward is to ask a new question, quoting the code you used (which may be based upon this question) and whatever error messages you recieved

Comment: @RichardTingle That's what he did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256196/correct-way-to-insert-favicon-link-tag-in-svg